# Should I say "in my tests" or "on my tests"?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say something like:

> *Using APC is great advice.  Performance increases a lot when you use it.  (100 to 1 on my tests)*

Should I say "on my tests" or "in my tests"?

Are any of those wrong?  Do those mean the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*On my tests* or *on tests* refers to a written examination. For example, a student who just took a history exam might say:

> I did well on my test today.

*In my tests* or *in tests* refers more to an actual series of tests which are run on something. So, if you are running a bunch of test cases on a new Java program, and your program passes all of them, you might say:

> The program did well in my tests.

I think your context is more of the second type, so I would suggest using *in my tests*.

Comment: Are there some sources which can back up this difference, or which can illustrate if there is a difference between eg US and UK usage? To my 50+ yr UK ear, 'did well on my test' sounds American and I would use 'did well in my test'.